# AWS CodeBuild - unable to commit and push changes to the CodeCommit repository

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have a pipeline in CodePipeline that is triggered on every push to the `main` branch in the CodeCommit repository.

The pipeline includes a Build step that executes commands that can change some files in the context of the current build pipeline. After these changes, I need to commit it, push it to the CodeCommit repository, and create a PR.

My `buildspec.yml` file:

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 16.x
    commands:
      # Here I am installing some NPM packages globally

  build:
    commands:
      # Here I run some commands that make changes to files in the repository

  post_build:
    commands:
      - git status

      # Set up the credential helper
      - git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
      - git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
      - git checkout -b l10n
      - git add .
      - git commit -m "New Changes"
      - git push origin l10n --force
      - aws codecommit create-pull-request --title "New PR" \
        --description "Pull request description" \
        --targets repositoryName=test,sourceReference=main,destinationReference=l10n
```

But this does not work and I get the following error:

```bash
[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Running command git status
HEAD detached at 839b707
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    locales/UK.json
    locales/de.json
    locales/es.json
    locales/et.json
    locales/fr.json

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Running command git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'

[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Running command git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true

[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Running command git checkout -b l10n
Switched to a new branch 'l10n'

[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Running command git add .

[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Running command git commit -m "New Changes"
Author identity unknown

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@06f7081cc58f.(none)')

[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Command did not exit successfully git commit -m "New Changes" exit status 128
[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/03/29 13:57:35 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: git commit -m "New Changes". Reason: exit status 128
```

My CodeBuild IAM Role has the `AWSCodeCommitFullAccess` policy attached.

Is it possible to configure git and pipeline to be able to commit and push changes made within the build step?

I also tried running the `git config --global user.email` , `git config --global user.name` commands but without success.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit of an odd setup as it sounds a bit as if you're creating an endless loop, if any build will automatically commit some changes, which then trigger another build, and so on.

The bit of an odd setup aside, the problem here seems to be that you haven't given Git a valid user to work with for the commit, as you probably already have realized. Any reason the `git config` didn't work for email and username? As an alternative, you could provision a .gitconfig file to the [build environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref.html), either via your own Docker image, or by creating the file as part of the build process. Though I haven't tested this, but it maybe worth a try.

In case that doesn't help, you can try to track down the issue by pausing the build and connecting to the build container, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/session-manager.html).

In any case, it might be worth reconsidering whether committing and pushing changes during a build is really necessary. Maybe there are alternatives to solve for whatever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The pipeline will be triggered only on the `main` branch and probably by some CloudWatch event regularly (the example was simplified). So there shouldn't be an endless loop. The issue is indeed with the git user authorization. I tried it with the email and username maybe I used the wrong credentials. Which email and username I should set here?

Comment: As this is executed automatically by the build environment, I'd use something that indicates this, for example "Build Bot" as user and "build-bot@your-company-name.com" as email.

Comment: I tried passing user and email and now getting the following error: `[Container] Running command git push origin l10n --force
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git-codecommit.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com': No such device or address
`

Comment: Hm, sorry, can't provide any further advise at the moment. You could try to debug it by logging in to the build instance like I've described earlier, or use a custom docker image where the Git credentials are already set up. Or a setup via SSH key might work. Would have to test this out first though, so these are just guesses.